# How can I evaluate this integral

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^2 2x}{1+x^2}\operatorname{d}x$$

I don't know how to solve. I calculated using Wolfram and get

$$\frac{\pi\sinh 2}{e^2}$$

Comment: You could do this with contour integration, if you know complex analysis, perhaps. But I'm sure there are other ways.

Comment: I've changed it to MathJax for you; you can learn how it works from [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @J.G just a minor remark it is better to use `\mathop{dx}` to get the correct spacing.

Comment: @zwim I've settled instead on `\operatorname{d}x`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your integral is $$\frac12\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{1-\cos 4x}{1+x^2}\operatorname{d}x=\frac{\pi-\Re\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{\exp 4ix}{1+x^2}\operatorname{d}x}{2}=\frac{\pi}{2}(1-\exp -4),$$using e.g. the Cauchy distribution's characteristic function,$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{\exp itx}{1+x^2}\operatorname{d}x=\exp -|t|.$$We can rewrite this result as $$\frac{\pi}{2e^2}\left(e^2-e^{-2}\right)=\frac{\pi\sinh 2}{e^2}.$$